# Cygwin GDB won't start

Tags: gdb, cygwin

I installed Cygwin g++ and gdb. g++ works but gdb doesn't output anything when started. It seems to have blocked right after start. What could cause this behaviour?

When I downgrade to gdb version 7.10.1-1 it works normally and outputs
[image]

But with any higher version (7.12.1-2, 8.0.1-1, 8.1.1-1, 8.2.1-1, 8.3.1-1, 9.2-1, 10.1-1) I just get no output at all.
[image]
This problem occurs on my old Win7 32bit PC as well as on my current Win10 64bit PC.
What could cause this issue?

Running GDB from the Cygwin Terminal also doesn't help:
[image]

Comment: have you started gdb from the Cygwin terminal ?

Comment: I am dealing with the same exact problem, have you found a solution by chance? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is caused by a missed dependency in the recent version for GDB package. Installing `libiconv` solves the problem.

https://sourceware.org/pipermail/cygwin/2021-February/247736.html

The missing depency issue should go away shortly.

Comment: Unfortunately running it from the Cygwin Terminal doesn't help.

Comment: I suggest you to followup on the Cygwin mailing list. I have no problem from Mintty or Cygwin.bat. I was able to make it work also from CMD

Comment: But this has to be a configuration issue. Because even with older versions down to 7.12 I've got the same problem. And I tested it on three different PCs now. Is there any documentation about dependencies to other Cygwin packages?

Comment: I asked at the mailing list and the dependency to libiconv is added. From now on this should not be an issue anymore.